# after migrating to ionic 5 and angular 8 multiple modal don't dismiss

Tags: modal-dialog, angular8, ionic5

I have an old application developed with ionic 4 and angular 7, there is a component that presents modal-A then, modal-A presents modal-B, when modal-B is dismissed, pass data to modal-A that dismiss and pass data to the component, now I want to switch to angular 8, the new app can present modal-A and modal-B, but when modal-B dismiss, modal-A does not dismiss, this is how the component presents modal-A:

```
const modal = await this.modalCtrl.create({
      component: SelectorItemsPage,
      componentProps: {
        item: this.item,
        title: this.text,
        service: this.service,
        filterFunction: this.filterFunction,
        sorterFunction: this.sorterFunction,
        createPopup: this.createPopup

      }
    });

    modal.onDidDismiss().then(data => {
      this.item = data.data
      this.selectedItem.emit(data.data)
      this.writeValue(this.item)
      modal.dismiss(this.item)
    })
    return await modal.present()
```

this is how modal-A presents modal-B:

```
    const modal = await this.modalCtrl.create({ component: this.createPopup })

    modal.onDidDismiss().then(item => {

      this.modalCtrl.dismiss(item.data)
    })

    return await modal.present()
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Set a **id** for each modal:

```
const modal = await this.modalCtrl.create({
  component: SelectorItemsPage,
  componentProps: {
    item: this.item,
    title: this.text,
    service: this.service,
    filterFunction: this.filterFunction,
    sorterFunction: this.sorterFunction,
    createPopup: this.createPopup
  },
  id: 'SelectorItems'
});
```

and

```
const modal = await this.modalCtrl.create({
    component: this.createPopup,
    id: 'Popup'
})
```

So when you close, pass the **id** as a parameter:

```
modal.dismiss(this.item, '', 'SelectorItems')
```

and

```
this.modalCtrl.dismiss(item.data, '', 'Popup')
```

More info:
[1] https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/20369
[2] https://github.com/mluis/ionic4-modal-modal-issue/pull/1/files < all credits